# C++ MFC reading Cstring from editbox for file reading (std::filesystem Exception unhandled memory problem)

Tags: c++, memory, mfc, std-filesystem

What my code is suppose to achieve is to read in the file names after given a **file path** input and output (switch 1: the files under the same folder)(switch 2: all the file names under the directory including sub-directories), and to not store the folder names into vector (1.png 2.png 3.png but not ChildFolder).

*If you need extra information regarding the folder structures it is provided in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70388291/898348).*

```
#define IDC_RADIO1                      1000
#define IDC_RADIO2                      1001
#define IDC_EDIT1                       1002
#define IDC_BUTTON1                     1003
#define IDC_LIST1                       1004
```

[This window app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWH05.png) have 2 radiobox, 1 editbox for user to input path name, 1 button to start the whole process, and 1 listbox to display the files read

Main function starts below:

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    string a;
    vector<string> caseOne,
                   caseTwo;
```

**The bottom two lines of code is where I have issues**

*The a = "C:\Users\User... code works but the output seems to have a array element logic problem going on where the output in the listbox is Nothing,1.png,2.png instead of 1.png,2.png* **Edit Note :this part works now**

The code  **directory_iterator list(str);**  seems to have a memory problem caused by
**a = enterPath.GetBuffer();** and I don't know what to do to fix it.

ErrorMessage *Unhandled exception at 0x7525B502 in MFCApplication3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x0133E438.*

The screen shot is provided below

I would ideally delete a = "C:\Users\User... and use a = enterP.. if it works

```
    a = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ParentFolder";//This line is used to test code, will move on to having user input to IDC_EDIT1

    //a = enterPath.GetBuffer();//Code I want to use

    path str = a;
    directory_iterator list(str);
    CListBox* listBox = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);

    UpdateData(TRUE);//update the data
    int checkRadio = GetCheckedRadioButton(IDC_RADIO1, IDC_RADIO2);
    switch (checkRadio)
    {
    case IDC_RADIO1:
        list = directory_iterator(a);                          //reset directory_iterator evertime button clicked to read new file
        for (auto& it : list) {                                //go through the directory_iterator list
            string filename1 = it.path().filename().string();  //get file names then convert filename into string format
            if (filename1.find(".") < filename1.length()/*or != string::npos*/ ) {    // find file name to rule out folders cause files contain '.'

                caseOne.push_back(filename1);       //putting the filenames into the vector
                CString fileunderPath;              //bottom 3 lines of code convert string to CString
                fileunderPath = filename1.c_str();
                listBox->AddString(fileunderPath);
            }
        }
        break;

    //same problem that should be resolved if case 1 is fixed
    case IDC_RADIO2://NOTE: NEED TO ADD CLEAR LISTBOX FUNCTION and vector
        list = directory_iterator(a);
        for (auto& dirEntry : recursive_directory_iterator(a)) {
            string filename2 = dirEntry.path().filename().string();
            if (filename2.find(".") != string::npos) { // find file name to rule out folders cause files contain '.'
                caseTwo.push_back(filename2);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    UpdateData(FALSE);//finish updating the data

}
```

## **Edit:**

This is what I want to achieve(UI screenshot)

[Working version where I predetermine the folder path for user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWH05.png)

[This is what I want user to enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0exR.png)

[Error message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9hpa.png)

[What the folder content looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH2MF.png)

[A child folder of the parent folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgGRo.png)

[The complete code of button 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Md1.png)

**I also found a new bug I didn't notice before**,The  output is png.1 png.2 instead of 1.png 2.png, this should not have happened since I made it work without problem when I used cout<<; a while back [Working version where I predetermine the folder path for user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWH05.png)

Comment: If "." is not found `find` returns `string::npos` which is `-1`.

Comment: Also I think you rather want `a = enterPath.GetString()` than `a = enterPath.GetBuffer()`.

Comment: Also: what is `if (filename2.find(".") < filename2.length())` supposed to do? The comment `// find file name to rule out folders cause files contain '.'` is not very clear. Otherwise I don't see anything obviously wrong here. What exactly is the _"memory problem"_ you mention? Also _"but the output seems to have a array element logic problem going on where the output in the listbox is Nothing,1.png,2.png instead of 1.png,2.png"_ what problem? You need to show an example of actual and desired behaviour.

Comment: BTW: Just `string a = enterPath;` should work fine. Anyway, you need to clarify the question and possibly show more relevant code.

Comment: Showing the __complete__ `OnBnClickedButton1` function may also help

Comment: @Jabberwocky So I changed **filename1.find(".") < filename1.length() ** to  **filename1.find(".") == 1**, and it works also , I don't really remember what my thought process was but now im swiching it for readability, the purpose of the code is to make the output change from **1.png 2.png ChildFolder --into-> 1.png 2.png**

Comment: @Jabberwocky  Upon futher inspection filename1.find(".") == 1 only seem to return files with only one letter before '.'  ,  so it will return 1.png or a.jpg but not 12.png of sadasd.png

Comment: The `directory_iterator` constructor throws an exception (as [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/directory_iterator)) when passing in invalid data. Which clearly, you are. The code you're running and the code you're showing aren't the same thing. Unrelated (probably), calling `GetBuffer` on a `CString` is not something you want. It is **not** a conversion operator.

Comment: Thanks you for the edits, but please __don't post pictures of source code__, is close to useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research,I changed my code and finally got it working

```
//Answer
string a;
CString stri;//Read text from edit control box and convert it to std::string
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->GetWindowText(stri);
a = CT2A(stri);

//This code is something I also tried but the string a it passed back is ""
/*CString b;
b = enterPath;//a control variable I added from IDC_EDIT1
a = CT2A(b);*/
```

Regarding the
**filename1.find(".") < filename1.length()**
it works becasue find() passes back the first location of the find character

so < filename1.length() means the return of the find() cannot be longer than the string it self, and when **nothing is found it returns -1** the if statement still runs but passes nothing to the AddString.(That why it felt like a band aid fix)

So the better way to write the if statement is either

```
if(filename1.find(".") != -1)
//or
if(filename1.find(".") != string::npos)//npos is -1
```

and since I found a better way to distinguish file names from folder in the #include filesystem, I ended up deleting the code above anyway

because for some reason I thought folder names can't have"." in them

```
//code I switched to 
if(is_regular_file(it))
```